# Reverse numbers

Tags: java, arrays

I'm  just starting out in programming. I am trying to develop a program that collects any amount  of integer numbers  and reverses the order in which they were entered. Say 1 6 8 9 4 9 becomes 9 4 9 8 6 1
This is what I did:

```
    System.out.println("Enter ten  numbers:");
    int[] n = new int[10];
    for (int i =0; i<n.length; i++)
    n[i] = input.nextInt();

 for(int i =0; i<n.length-1; i++)
     for (int j= n.length-1; j>0; j--){
    int temp = n[i];
    n[i] = n[j];
    n[j] = ;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want to do is print them out in the reverse order, why reverse the array? Just print them:

```
   System.out.println("Enter ten  numbers:");
    int[] n = new int[10];
    for (int i =0; i<n.length; i++) {
       n[i] = input.nextInt();
    }
    for ( int i=n.length-1; i >=  0; i-- ) {
       System.out.println( n[i] );
    }
```

Comment: You are right on the printing part but is it possible to collect the numbers going into the println statement back into the original array?  If so will that reverse the original array?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to swap-reverse all numbers you can do this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.length / 2; i++)
{
    int temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[array.length - i - 1];
    array[array.length - i - 1] = temp;
}
```

Comment: There's a tiny flaw with your code. What happens when the length of the array is odd? :)

Comment: oh in that case he still can cast to `double`, but you're right.

Comment: In this case, yes. But in his question, he states "that collects any amount of integer numbers".